how to use loops with conditional statement in typescript
For days i cant figure out how to get the for loop to iterate over all items and then run the conditional. So I want it to iterate overall the channels (returned from mysql query) and then check if its true. It will run the conditionals on each item as they pass the loop. When the conditional is true it will execute but it well then move to the next step and execute the else. Ive tried mapping, probably incorrectly, and even tried to turn it into a JSON. I even started messing with Message collections.
It works in Javascript so not sure what typescript is doing. Any help is much appreciated.
export = {
  name: 'addfav',
  aliases: ['Addfav'],
  type: CommandTypes.PrefixCommand,
  channelWhitelist: ['1147233774938107966'],
  ownerOnly: true,
  async execute(message: Message): Promise<void> {
    if (!message.mentions.channels.map((m) => m).length) {
      await message.reply('Did you forget to add the channel?');
    } else {
      let getChannel = await message.content.replace(/\D/g, '');
      let isAdded = await checkfav(message.author.id);
      for (var i = 0; i < isAdded.length; i++) {
        if (isAdded[i].channel === getChannel) {
          await message.reply('You already have a channel');
          break;
        } else {
          await addfav(getChannel);
          await message.reply('Channel added');
        }
      }
    }
  },
};


It's not really clear what your question is? Did you leave something out of this statement... "When the conditional is true it."? Please [edit] your question to describe the problem; explain what you expect to happen vs what actually happens

I assume isAdded is a bool? So what is isAdded.length supposed to do?

What exactly does not work? Is there a compilation error when converting from TS to JS?

so sorry, I didnt realize I hadnt finished the sentence! how frustrated i was.

isAdded is a mysql call and returns user, channel. The exact same code works in JS but in TS it checks the conditionals on each loop

In your scenario you don't need to iterate over favorited channels. You just need to check if channel is already in favorites. You can use some to achieve it:
export = {
  name: 'addfav',
  aliases: ['Addfav'],
  type: CommandTypes.PrefixCommand,
  channelWhitelist: ['1147233774938107966'],
  ownerOnly: true,
  async execute(message: Message): Promise<void> {
    if (!message.mentions.channels.map((m) => m).length) {
      await message.reply('Did you forget to add the channel?');
      return;
    }
    let channelName = await message.content.replace(/\D/g, '');
    // get favaorited channels
    const favoritedChannels = await checkfav(message.author.id);
    const isFavorite = favoritedChannels.some((fav) => fav.channel === channelName)  
    if(isFavorite) {
      await message.reply('You already have this channel favorited');
      return;
    }
    await addfav(channelName);
    await message.reply('Channel added');
  },
};

However, if you do need to iterate over an array and run async function on each element, here is how you can do it:
  const favoritedChannels = await checkfav(message.author.id);
  for await (const channel of favoritedChannels) {
    await doSomething(channel);
  }

Or you can run in parallel:
  const favoritedChannels = await checkfav(message.author.id);
  const results = await Promise.all(favoritedChannels.map(channel => doSomething(channel));


thank you@ Can I run a promise inside a promise statement? I guess only one way to find out! I tried some before and it still looped through the conditionals on every round. I likely did it wrong so ill check this out. <3
